# Why Are Even and Odd Regge Trajectories Degenerate?

Tags: string-theory, research-level

The Gribov-Froissart projection treats even angular momentum differently from odd angular momentum.
But in QCD, I believe that the odd trajectories interpolate the even trajectories--- the two trajectories are degenerate. Is there a way of understanding why the even-odd trajectories are degenerate? Is is a symmetry argument? Can you find a natural system where they are not degenerate?

A quick google search revealed this reference, which doesn't answer the question, but gives an experimental signature for the degeneracy: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-pub-0576.pdf , There is probably excellent data by now on this.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the closely related concept of parity doubling in hadron spectrum, see e.g. this review: http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0704.1639

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are the even and odd Regge trajectories degenerate?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14791/)